# Finding the area of a parallelogram given four 3D vertices

Tags: linear-algebra

The points are $(1,1,1)$, $(2,3,4)$, $(6,5,2)$, and $(7,7,5)$.

What I tried was the cross product, and getting the length of the cross product, I got an answer of $\sqrt{3}$, but that is wrong. Then I thought about getting the distances between the two vertices, but I think there could be a better solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A,B,C,D$ the 4 edges of the parallelogram. The area is going to be $$\left\|\vec{AB}-\frac{\left<\vec{AB},\vec{AD}\right>}{\|\vec{AD}\|^2}\vec{AD}\right\|\cdot \|\vec{AD}\|$$

Notice that $\frac{\left<\vec{AB},\vec{AD}\right>}{\|\vec{AD}\|^2}\vec{AD}$ is the orthogonal projection of $\vec{AB}$ over $\vec{AD}$. Therefore, $\vec{AB}-\frac{\left<\vec{AB},\vec{AD}\right>}{\|\vec{AD}\|^2}\vec{AD}$ will be the altitude. The claim follow.